# Solve $ y^2y’’ = y’, y(0) = 1, y’(0) = 1 $

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve the ODE with the initial conditions:

$$
y^2y’’ = y’, y(0) = 1, y’(0) = 1
$$

---

I did the substitution:

$$
y’ = z 
$$
$$
y’’ = z’ = \frac{dz}{dx} = \frac{dz}{dy}\frac{dy}{dx} = z \frac{dz}{dy}
$$

Putting in the ODE:

$$
y^2z \frac{dz}{dy} = z \Rightarrow y^2 \frac{dz}{dy} = 1 \Rightarrow \frac{dz}{dy} = \frac{1}{y^2} \Rightarrow dz = \frac{1}{y^2}dy
$$

By integration we get:

$$
z = -\frac{1}{y} + C \Rightarrow y’ = - \frac{1}{y} + C
$$

Using the initial conditions we get:

$$
1 = -\frac{1}{1} + C \Rightarrow C = 2
$$

Therefore:

$$
y’ = -\frac{1}{y} + 2
$$

Now I am not sure how to continue.

Comment: $$y' = \frac{2-y}{y} \implies \frac{y}{2-y} dy = dx \underbrace{\implies}_{y \to 2-y} - \frac{2-y}{y} dy = dx$$

Comment: Your first order equation is separable as well, so you can use the same technique you used (where you said “by integration we get”) before. Just rewrite $y’$ as $dy/dx$ and separate.

Comment: @mattos Is it legal to do $y->2-y$? If so, why?

Comment: It's just a change of variable. Use $u = 2-y$ instead if you are used to that.

Comment: @mattos And how did you get to $\frac{2-y}{y}?$

Comment: Sorry, typo, it should have been $$y' = \frac{2y-1}{y}$$ then separate and make the substitution $u = 2y - 1$.

Comment: @mattos worked, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

$$y’ = -\frac{1}{y} + 2$$
$$y’ = -\frac{1}{y} + \dfrac {2y}y$$
$$y’ = \frac{2y-1}{y}$$
$$\dfrac {y}{2y-1}dy = dx$$
Then integrate both sides.
$$\int \dfrac {y \, dy}{2y-1} = \int dx$$
Substitute $u=2y-1 \implies du=2dy$
and $y=\dfrac {u+1}2$
$$\dfrac 14 \int \dfrac {u+1}{u}du = \int dx$$
$$\dfrac 14 \int \left (1+\dfrac {1}{u} \right ) du = \int dx$$

Answer (score 1):

$y^2y''=y'$

Write as
$y''=\frac{y'}{y^2}$

Integrate both sides

$y'=-1/y +C$

$y'(0)=1,y(0)=1\to C=2$

$y'=-1/y+2$

$y=\frac{1}{2} \left(W\left(e^{4 x+1}\right)+1\right)$

Where $W(z)$ is Lambert $W$ function which solves $we^w=z$

The implicit form is

$x=\frac{1}{4} (2 y+\log (2 y-1)-1)$